# How to show that there is an $x$ such that $f'(x)=2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

So I have that $f: [1,4] \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable and $f(1)=0, f(2)=1$ and $f(4)=8$. How can I show that there is an $x$ such that $f'(x)=2$? 
I have shown, by the mean value theorem, that there exists an $x$ such that $f'(x)=1$ since $\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2-1} =1$ but I dont know how to show that there is an $x$ such that $f'(x)=2$.

Comment: You have $f(1)$, $f(2)$, and $f(4)$. Try the Mean Value Theorem with more combinations than just $f(1)$ and $f(2)$.

Comment: *Hint*: Functions which are the derivative of another function satisfy the *Intermediate Value theorem*.

Answer (score 1):

As $x$ increases from $2$ to $4$:

- the quantity $f(x)-f(1)$ varies continuously from $f(2)-f(1)=1$ to $f(4)-f(1)=8$;
- the quantity $x-1$ increases continuously from $2-1=1$ to $4-1=3$;
- and so the quantity $F(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ varies continuously from $F(2) = \frac{1}{1}=1$ to $F(4) = \frac{8}{3}$.

Applying the Intermediate Value Theorem, since $F(2) = 1 < 2 < \frac{8}{3} = F(4)$, there is a value of $x$ between $2$ and $4$ such that $F(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = 2$.

Applying the Mean Value Theorem to the interval $[1,x]$ over which the equation $\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = 2$ is true, one finds $a \in (1,x)$ such that $f'(a)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Try the mean value theorem again but for other points: $$\frac{f(4)-f(2)}{4-2} = \frac{8-1}{4-2} = \frac 7 2$$

The mean value theorem for first interval $[1,2]$ gives that there must exist one point $\xi_1$ on that interval for which $f'(\xi_1)=1$.

The mean value theorem for second interval $[2,4]$ gives that there must exist one point $\xi_2$ on that interval for which $f'(\xi_2) = \frac 7 2$

Now because of Darboux's theorem (every function that results from the differentiation of another function has the intermediate value property), we can apply the *intermediate value theorem* between these two points.Since $1<2<\frac 7 2$, the value $2$ must be assumed somewhere on the interval given by $[\xi_1,\xi_2]$

Comment: Derivatives have the intermediate value property even if they are not continuous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: As mentioned by @Bernard, $f'$ satisfies the IVT even if it is discontinuous.

Comment: @MartinR Yep, I edited.

Comment: This result is known as *Darboux's theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

You know that exists $a$ with $f'(a) = 1$. Similarly there is $b$ with $f'(b) = \frac{f(4) - f(1)}{4-1} = 8/3 > 2$. Now apply [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: Can I use the Darboux'theorem on $f(1)=0$ and $f(4)=8$? Since $0<2<4$ and $f$ is differentiable on $[1,4]$?